# Autocompletar contenidos en un documento de texto con cmd.exe

Tags: cmd, batch

Tengo el siguiente temp.txt con estos contenidos:

```
01. título a.flac  
02. título b.flac  
03. título c.flac
```

que convierto en el siguiente Plantilla metaflac.txt:

```
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER= "01. título a.flac"  
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER= "02. título b.flac"  
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER= "03. título c.flac"
```

con este comando en un bat:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G IN (temp.txt) DO ECHO metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER= "%%G">> "Plantilla metaflac.txt"
```

A partir de ahí me gustaría autocompletar el campo TRACKNUMBER (ej. TRACKNUMBER=1 a TRACKNUMBER=99)
y el campo TITLE (TITLE="título a" a TITLE="título z")

Gracias por adelantado por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Con el for que has usado, casi tienes la solución. Lo único que necesitas cambiar es la parte de los `tokens` y `delims`. En `delims`debes indicar que caracter te sirve como delimitador, en tu caso el ".", En `tokens` le dices, con la partición anterior, que trozos(tokens) quieres usar.

Con el delimitador "." tu lineas se parten en

- Token 1: 01
- Token 2:  título a
- Token 3: flac

Con el for adaptado así:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%g IN (temp.txt) DO (
    set title=%%h
    set title=!title:~1!
    set /a track=10000%%g %% 10000
    ECHO metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="!title!" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="!track!">> "Plantilla metaflac.txt"
)
```

El for te genera una variable por cada token, siendo la primera la `%%g`, y las siguientes por orden alfabético.
con esto creo que puedes componer mejor tu fichero.

Resultado:

```
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="título a" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="1"
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="título b" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="2"
metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="título c" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER="3"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte pero sigo teniendo que solucionar el espacio antes del título y el tracknumber del 1 al 9 (o 0 a 9) debe ser sin cero delante, es decir 1, 2, 3... y no 01, 02, 03...

Comment: @user84131, para obtener ese resultado hay que añadir un poco más de código, pero se puede conseguir. Actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Muy agradecido Mallenat. Todavía no lo he puesto en práctica pero ahora sí tiene buena pinta.

Comment: Este es el archivo bat completo por cierto, he hecho una pequeña modificación para el primer inconveniente que he mencionado, no sé si estará bien:

Comment: `CHCP 1252
IF EXIST *.flac (
    DIR /B *.flac > temp.txt
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%g IN (temp.txt) DO (
        set title=%%h
        set title=!title:~1!
        set /a track=%%g + 0
        ECHO metaflac --set-tag=TITLE="!title!" --set-tag=TRACKNUMBER=!track! "%%g.%%h.flac">> "Plantilla metaflac.txt"
    )
    DEL temp.txt
) ELSE (
    ECHO La carpeta no contiene flacs.> "Plantilla metaflac.txt"
)
EXIT`

Comment: Los inconvenientes que mencionaba son que después de tracknumber me falta el nombre del archivo ej. "01. título a.flac" y que para los números correspondientes a 8 y 9 devuelve 7 con las pruebas que he hecho. Para lo primero he puesto "%%g.%%h.flac" a tu comando que no sé si estará bien.

Comment: @user84131, efectivamente hay un problema con el tracknumber. El problema es que ms-dos piensa que `08` es un numero octal y no realiza bien el cálculo. Prueba esta forma `set /a track=10000%%g %% 10000`